# Rxjs/Typescript: Trying to filter a stream on array intersection

Tags: rxjs, observable, typescript2.0

Have a stream, wherein the object contains and array of string. I have a filter which is another array of string. The filter should only emit those items where the intersection of the array is not empty.

This is the psuedo code of what I want to do.

```
genreFilter: string["poetry", "fiction"]

this.books$ = this.bookInventoryService.getBooks()
    .filter(book => {
        for( let genre of genreFilter) {
            if (book.genres.contains(genre) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to do array intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an Rx question, but if you are compiling to ES6 you can create a `Set` from the filter and then use the Array#some to determine if there are any intersections.

```
const genreFilter: Set<string> = new Set(["poetry", "fiction"]);

this.books$ = this.bookInventoryService.getBooks()
    .filter(book => book.genres.some(genre => genreFilter.has(genre)));
```

If `Set` is not available you can still do it with an `Array` if the comparison set is small. Or if the set is large you could create an object out of the filter so you get O(1) lookup:

```
   const genreFilter = ["poetry", "fiction"]
      .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = true 
        return obj;
      }, {});

   this.books$ = this.bookInventoryService.getBooks()
        .filter(book => book.genres.some(genre => genreFilter[genre]));
```

Comment: The `bookInventoryService.getBooks()` returns an `Observable<book[]>`

so the lambda 
'this.books$ =` `this.bookInventoryService.getBooks()` 
`.filter(book=> book.genres` doesn't seem to work since it says `book` is a a `book[]` not an individual `book` object.

do I need a `foreach` on the book?

Comment: you shouldn't need to, you could just flatten the books array: `bookInventoryService.getBooks().flatMap(books => books).filter(/**/)`